# Filter a column on Oracle SQL developer like '%+%'

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I want to display all the names in a table that contains the character '+' but it doesn't work on Oracle SQL developer, while the column contains names with '+'

```
Select *
from Table where NAME like '%+%';
```

==> I got an empty output

Example:

[image]

Could you help me please ?!

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.  I reckon your logic is correct as-is.

Comment: Strange, I get Samuel and Eric. https://dbfiddle.uk/1aq8izc2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this statement:

```
Select *
from Table where NAME like '%' || chr(43) || '%';
```

Thank you